# Use of . / in c++ - operator or float?

Tags: c++

The following piece of code outputs 0 and I'm not sure why. I'm not sure what the meaning of of . is in this context. Is it an operator or is it just indicating a float? Is it related to *Int?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int *Int = new int;
   *Int = 1 / 2 * 2 / 1. * 2. / 4 * 4;
   cout << *Int;    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a pointer and `new` for `Int`?

Comment: You might want to invest in [a couple of decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) about C++.

Comment: I've just started learning, thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: `2.` is a `double`, just as `2.0` is. A `float` would be `2.f` or `2.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an operator. It indicates a `double`, not a `float`.

`42.` means `42.0`, and `.42` means `0.42`. A `.` alone is a compiler error (rather than `0.0`).

If you add a trailing `f`, it will become a `float` instead of `double`, e.g. `1.f`, `.1f`, `1.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

`1 / 2 == 0`, `0` multiplied by anything is `0` again.